# Executing code/functions when app is terminated

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Context - Im building a location tracking app for family members to monitor each other, once the member approves permission for location Im able to get location details, but when they close/terminate their app, it doesn't update location details to Firebase.

Question - I want a background process that executes something even if the app is terminated, should start after install/first run, then run on its own even if app is terminated, a relative example would be WhatsApp receiving new message notifications and message content even without opening the app.

What I tried - I checked isolates, but couldn't get around it with tech implementation for my case, tried work_manager, background_fetch packages but not very sure if that's the only way, I see there is need for this background thread to run something on almost every app case, so Im think there is some better/native way of doing it.

I see Firebase push notifications working this way, they show up when app is terminated, so I believe there is a way.

Any suggestions/help is much appreciated.